# MakeyMakey + Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to use the MakeyMakey with the Arduino (not as an Arduino) and then use a USB to TTL module to send the keys pressed to the Arduino. Is this possible? Do I have to reprogram?

Comment: No you can't the makeymakey and the usb-to-serial adapter are both usb clients. You need one host and one clients for usb. You could alter the firmware to send serial info using D0 and D1 on the header on the backside, but that's not that easy.

Comment: Why not have the MakeyMakey communicate using its USART intead?

Comment: Possibility, but the USB host shield worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possibility is to use HOST SHIELD 
http://www.circuitsathome.com/products-page/arduino-shields

Arduino is now as host
Makey is keyboard